# Match nodes with two different values in same property Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this kind of graph:
[image]

I want to retrieve all Products that have pending or open requests. This is how Im trying

```
MATCH (s:ServiceRequest {srStatus: "Open"} OR {srStatus: "Pending"}) -[:FOR]->(p:Product) RETURN p
```

But this does not work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (s:ServiceRequest)-[:FOR]->(p:Product)
WHERE s.srStatus IN ["Open", "Pending"]
RETURN p;
```

and so should this:

```
MATCH (s:ServiceRequest)-[:FOR]->(p:Product)
WHERE s.srStatus = "Open" OR s.srStatus = "Pending"
RETURN p;
```